# Alternativas menos negativas a "desafortunadamente"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos

Estoy escribiendo un correo orientado a negocios. Quiero decir "Desafortunadamente, blah blah blah, porque bleh bleh bleh", con el objetivo de dar a conocer un hecho que no es beneficioso para la otra parte.

Me preguntaba si no existiría alguna frase que pudiera funcionar como alternativa, ya que encuentro ésta muy negativa. Simplemente, no es bueno para el negocio.

¿Alguna idea?

¡Gracias de antemano!

**Edición**

Al final del día decidí no usar palabra alguna para introducir la frase en cuestión, sino que use una frase positiva y luego simplemente expuse la parte negativa; algo como "Blah blah blah, pero bleh bleh bleh".

Comment: En mi opinión "desafortunadamente" es una opción menos negativa que las alternativas "lamentablente" y "desgraciadamente".

Comment: Lo es, @Nico. Aunque bien la respuesta de Nicolás me una buena idea de algo que puede funcionar para mi caso en particular, sí creo que "desafortunadamente" sea de lo menos negativo en su categoría, en parte porque lleva la connotación de que es algo que no está en nuestras manos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una opción que no suena tan negativa es introducir la "noticia" directamente con una frase, por ejemplo:

> **No ha sido posible** blah blah blah, porque bleh bleh bleh.
>   **Lamento comunicarles que** blah blah blah, porque bleh bleh bleh.

Ello, dado que los sinónimos de [desafortunado](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/desafortunado) tienen todos, como es de esperarse, una connotación negativa.

Comment: Aunque concuerdo con Nico (el de los comentarios a la pregunta) en que "lamentable" suena más negativo que "desafortunado", me quedo con la respuesta porque me dio la idea de no usar una palabra como tal, sino simplemente dar la frase, como en el primer ejemplo que expones, @Nicolás. ¡Gracias!